# JWT ES256 regex, not able to add exclusions

Tags: java, regex

I created a pattern to match JWT(**ES256**).

```
(([a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+)+)9).*?([a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+)+).(.*?)(?=[\s\"\\,\)\]])
```

Which works and finds jwt tokens in the logs for further masking.
But it also has a lot of false positives and matches content it shouldn't match.

> Example string:
>
> (traceId content was masked, I changed it to jwt to reproduce issue)

```
[traceId=eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJ0ZXN0Iiwic3ViIjoiam9obiIsImF1ZCI6ImNvbm5vciIsImlhdCI6NjY2NjY2NjY5OSwiZXhwIjo2NjcwNTc0NTk5fQ.fh3NKfJMO3QNYrC6Lq6TG5qdJ8kgQmubfJh5bqTengiVB8q2MdfjNwVajZNMpaPKOCSoReVuRcVyJoFQwT16-w] DEBUG something
```

I want to add exclusions with the negative lookbehind, to match only if it doesn't contain certain words like ***traceId*** or other params. But it's not working for this pattern.

```
(?<=(?<!traceId))(([a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+)+)9).*?([a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+)+).(.*?)(?=[\s\"\\,\)\]])
```

Sidenote: the matches aren't at the beginning all the time as with *traceId* case.
They can be in any part of the string.

---

Java 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude `[traceId=` you might write the pattern as

```
(?<!\[traceId=)\b[\w-]+\.[\w-]+\.[\w-]+\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YHVrO3/1)

Or if you want to match a `9` before the first dot and assert one of the chars listed in the character class or the end of the string at the end of the pattern:

```
(?<!\[traceId=)\b[\w-]*9\.[\w-]+\.[\w-]+(?=[\s\"\\,)\]]|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rExDdx/1)

Comment: Great thanks. First approach also matches class names and ips.
But the second regex works well